# Isn't big O of x^2+x technically bigger than big O of x^2?

Tags: big-o

I know that we are only supposed to think about the larger power term, but for smaller values of `x` the `+x` will matter, methinks. Granted with really large values of `x` it will not.

Comment: "Technically" isn't a word that applies here! :-)

Comment: The whole point of claiming that they are 'technically' the same is for really large values of x. If x goes toward 1 million, 1 million squared will matter a lot more in each term than 1 million.

Comment: The whole point of Big O is "really large values of x"

Comment: The definition of the notation O() is such that O(x^2+x) is the same as O(x^2). None of them depend on what happens for small values of x. O(...) only depends on the asymptotic behavior of the expression.

Comment: @Hunter: Even saying something like "they are the same" (let alone "bigger") is a very non-trivial statement that really needs to be made precise!

Answer (score 5):

Big O is a limit to infinity... you don't care about the small values, so you can ignore the +x

Answer (score 4):

Big-Oh isn't about the smaller values of n.

So: **No**, it's not bigger. O(n^2+n) = O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

The point of 'big-O' notation is to talk about the behavior when `n` gets large. Yes there will be a difference between `n^2 + n` and `n`for small `n`, but for small `n`, we don't need to worry about performance.

`O(n^2 + n)` refers to the limiting behavior, which is not 'technically' any different from `O(n^2)` since the limit as n approaches infinity of `(n^2 + n)/n^2` is 1 (which is a constant, the value 'one' is not significant either.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing two algorithms and the are both Ox^2, then you may have to look at the next significant terms. The point is, the big-O analysis usually allows you to determine which algoritm is better. Generally, this is done with only the highest order term.

Comment: No, you wouldn't look at lower order terms.  You'd look at the coefficient.

Comment: True. In the cases that have been shown, there are no coefficients on the x^2 term. Otherwise, that info would be important.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.

Big-O only describes the order of complexity, and always carries an implied proportionality constant.  The value of this constant is FAR more important than lower-order terms, even for small x.